# How can I assign a value to a Char array?

Tags: arrays, delphi, char, variable-assignment

Say I have the variable:

```
Var question : array[1..50] of char;
```

When I do:

```
question := 't'; //What is the correct way to change the value?
```

It returns an error:

> Incompatible types: 'array[1..50] of Char' and 'Char'

Note: I want to have a max string size of 50 chars, not 50 different chars.

The reason for this question is that I have a record in another unit(This is just a basic example, not what I actually have written above) In that unit I have a Record, which I can't use the string data type in(Or is there a way? please explain if there is). I just need to know how to give an array of chars a value.

Comment: What error do you get when you declare a string in a record? This is definitly possible and much simpler than juggling with array's of chars.

Comment: Incompatible types: 'array[1..50] of Char' and 'Char'
is the one. However if I match the amount of characters in the string with the range of the array, it works.

Comment: Just a suggestion, please go through this tutorial, it will help you to understand some delphi constructs and basics... http://delphi.about.com/od/beginners/a/delphicourse.htm

Comment: that is the error you get for *this* declaration, it can't be the error you are getting when you try to use a string in a record.

Comment: Thanks Nain, I would read it, but I'm a little short on time at the moment with the project. However I will read it after even though the topic will change. @Lieven, I'll supply the whole project code.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

While Delphi strings and arrays of char are related, they are not the same.

Delphi overloads assignment of strings and literals (char and string) to array of chars, but only when the lower array bound is zero.

The following code works for me in D2007 and Delphi XE:

```
  var x : array[0..49] of char;
  begin
    x:='b';  // char literal
    x:='bb';  // string literal      
  end.
```

If I change the [0 to [1 it fails. This limitation probably simplifies the language helper that takes care of this, and probably the feature is only meant for dealing with converted C  structs where arrays always have lower bound 0.

Comment: @Skeela87, good if it works for you but it should have worked (compiled) with plain strings too. It compiles for me using *Delphi 5* (after removing var in the record declaration) and *Delphi 2010*

Comment: Lieven: I assume he wants to blockwrite the record. And no, then you can only use shortstring, but that has a 255 char limit and a lead length byte.

Answer (score 3):

Are you sure that you can't use string data type in a record?
Anyways...

```
type
  TCharArray = array[Char] of Char;

function StringToArray(Str: string): TCharArray;
begin
  FillChar(Result, High(Byte), #0);
  Move(Str[1], Result, length(Str));
end;

procedure TestCharArray;
var
  question: TCharArray;
begin
  question := StringToArray('123');
  ShowMessage(PChar(@question));
end;
```

Also take a look at `StrPCopy` function.

Comment: Nevermind, I know what I forgot to do. Put it in the TForm Class

Comment: But Using your code with StringToArray('test'). I get the error: Incompatible types: 'array[0..65535] of Char' and 'System.TArray<System.Char>'

Answer (score 2):

If you don't need unicode characters, you should just define your string like `string[50]`.

After that you don't need any functions or conversions to work with that string, and it'll be just as easy to read and write it to a file.

```
Hscores = record
var
  _topscore : integer;
  _topname : string[50];
end;
```

Comment: This is the most idiomatic way to deal with fixed length ansi string data within a record.  +1 for pointing out that String[50] is really a fixed-length string composed of AnsiChar (byte size) elements.

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure you can use strings in record types.

This blog entry shows an example: http://delphi.about.com/od/beginners/a/record_type.htm

In order to assign a value to the Char array, you have to index it, like any other array:

```
question[1] := 't';
```

Comment: I tried to use the example in the link you gave, I still got that error. I'm not that great with delphi yet, so I might have done something wrong. Although I just figured out if I put array[1..5] of char, I have to use a string that's 5 characters long. Now I need a way of being able to put the length I like. Thanks for the reply, but perhaps I should rephrase my question, I'll make an edit in the main post.

Comment: Here in this case, index start with 1, so (question[0] := 't';) will again give compile time array bound error, question[1] := 't'; is better :)

Comment: @Nains: gah! so long since I've used Delphi.